# My procedural pool tile texture strectches quite a bit on the pool walls

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders

I hope I don't cause any inconveniences but I've been having quite the trouble applying a procedural pool tile texture to my pool in a blender project, let me provide an image:
[image: Pool tile texture stretched on the walls]

I've tried to uv unwrap the texture by adding seams and rotating it, moving it, etc. But nothing has worked out so far, it's also worth mentioning that the Texture Coordinate node has its object coordinate connected to a noise and brick texture node, does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Hello could you please share your object or at least show a screenshot of your Shader Editor? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Connect the UV texture coordinate to the noise and brick textures (instead of object) so it will use your UV map to map them to your object. (Object uses object coordinates which are 3D - brick texture is 2D - this is why the texture is stretching with object coordinates - UV map is also 2D so it will work with the brick texture nicely).